# Are bitcoin wallets money service businesses (MSB)?

Tags: legal

Do hosted wallet services located in the USA need to register with the fenCEN as a MSB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the business is based in the US, yes.

Edit: IANAL, but in my opinion a wallet service clearly falls into the category of *money transmitter* according to [FinCEN's virtual currency regulations](http://fincen.gov/statutes_regs/guidance/html/FIN-2013-G001.html).

Comment: Please provide an argument or source of information that supports your answer.

Comment: @Murch, answer edited with FinCEN reference. I actually learned about it from a local bitcoin meetup where US regulation was heavily discussed. Of course, most regulations are normally open to different interpretations. A good lawyer can work miracles.